# "One of the provided arguments is not acceptable." when I try to update a share link permission

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

According to the article here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/permission-update

I'm trying to update the permission for a share link in OneDrive by changing the "roles" attribute from "write" to "read", however, I'm getting always the following response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "badArgument",
    "message": "One of the provided arguments is not acceptable.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-08-28T08:20:48",
      "request-id": "53d3a458-74e4-4f54-b322-5bb39663f0a2"
    }
  }
}
```

below my request:

```
PATCH
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/94a7de87-ecd9-4e1e-961b-5e59b1f0c012/drive/items/01NODCI4ESPCGY2GUN65BLN3Z3RBDTPIBT/permissions/8dd584e6-adca-4736-8e32-659ac99527bc
```

BODY:

```
{
  "roles": ["read"]
}
```

I'm interested to know also if is there a way to remove a single user from a share link instead of deleting it completely causing the share breaking for every user included or the only thing that we can change is the **roles** property?

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you get a different result if you drive the same request on an item located in a drive from OneDrive?

Comment: Thank you for your reply I get the same result

Comment: @GiulianoDeLuca-MVP i m facing same issue did u get any solution?

Comment: @Amir I solved using the SharePoint rest api

Comment: @GiulianoDeLuca-MVP can you please post the answer here or just share the details